# $det(Q)det(\overline{Q})=det(Q)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

It is not obvious at least to me why $\det (Q) \overline{ \det Q} =\det(Q)^2$ where $Q \in M_{nxn} (\mathbb{C})$ 
This  is needed for the following:(note that || stands for det not absolute value)

A matrix $Q \in M_{nxn} (C)$ is called **unitary** if $QQ^*=I$, where $Q^*=\overline{Q^t}.$ Prove that if $Q$ is a unitary matrix, then $|det(Q)|=1$

$$1=|I|=|Q \overline{Q^t}|
       =|Q| \overline{|Q^t|}
       =|Q|\overline{|Q|}
       =|Q|^2\ \Rightarrow 1=|Q|^2 \iff |Q|=1$$

---

guessing $|Q|$ is some complex number 
        $$|Q|\overline{|Q|} =|x+iy|\overline{|x+iy|}=(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2-i^2y^2=x^2+y^2 $$
but it dosent seem right that |Q| has to be 1.

Comment: There is a difference between $\det(Q)\overline{\det(Q)}=\det(Q)^2$ and $\det(Q)\overline{\det(Q)}=|\det(Q)|^2$.  It looks like both show up in your calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the line $|Q|\overline{|Q|}=|Q|^2$.  One the LHS of this expression, it appears that you are using $|\cdot|$ to represent the determinant.  On the RHS of the expression, you use $|\cdot|$ to represent the absolute value of the determinant.  On the RHS, you may want $|\det(Q)|^2$.

More details: $|Q|=\det(Q)$ is a complex number, lets call it $z$.  Then $|Q|\overline{|Q|}=z\overline{z}=|z|^2$, i.e., the magnitude of $z$, squared.  Observe that since these are complex numbers, $z^2$ is not necessarily the same as $|z|^2$.  Therefore $|Q|\overline{|Q|}=|\det(Q)|^2$.

Since $|\det(Q)|^2=1$ and $|\det(Q)|$ is a nonnegative number, it is $1$.